# page.evaluate: ReferenceError: _reportWebVitals is not defined playwright

Tags: javascript, reactjs, puppeteer, playwright, core-web-vitals

I want to get a web-vitals metrics result from the reportWebVitals function but unable to achieve the result using playwright.

```
import type { ReportHandler } from 'web-vitals';

const reportWebVitals = (onPerfEntry?: ReportHandler) => {
  if (onPerfEntry && onPerfEntry instanceof Function) {
    import('web-vitals').then(({ getCLS, getFID, getFCP, getLCP, getTTFB }) => {
      getCLS(onPerfEntry);
      getFID(onPerfEntry);
      getFCP(onPerfEntry);
      getLCP(onPerfEntry);
      getTTFB(onPerfEntry);
    });
  }
};

export default reportWebVitals;
```

`import reportWebVitals from '../src/reportWebVitals';`

```
test.only('Performance Checks using web-vitals library', async ({ browser }) => {
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();
  await page.goto(HOME_PAGE_URL, { waitUntil: 'networkidle' });
  const getVitals = (args) => {
    console.log('args', args);
    
  };
  await page.evaluate(async () => {
    reportWebVitals(getVitals);
  });
});
```

Comment: `evaluate` runs in the browser where it doesn't have access to things you've defined in Node. I'm not sure what's in `reportWebVitals`, but maybe just call it directly without the eval?

Comment: I tried calling without evaluate function it didn't work throws me an error "page. goto: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED at ".